# How can you get the result of $f(2015) + g(2015)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

This question is related to the function topic. Here we are faced with two functional parametric equations that are added together and their value is also written in terms of the parameter $x$. Pay attention that $f$, $g$ and $y$ are different functions:

$$ f(2x+1) + g(x-1) = 3x+2 $$
$$ f\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) + 3y\left(\frac{1-2x}{2x}\right) = \frac{1}{2x} + 4 $$

Now the basic question is how to get the result of $f(2015) + g(2015)$? I tried to get their main rule by changing the expression variables inside the functions but it was very long and involved confusing calculations. What is the best way to answer this question?

Comment: Related to an earlier question [What is the result of f(2015) + g(2015)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4820780/89922)

Comment: i guess it should be g instead of y in the second equation.

Comment: If $u=\frac1{2x}$ then the second equation becomes $$f(1+2u)+3y(u-1)=u+4.$$

Comment: Let $A = y(1006)$, and deduce $f(2015)$ using the second equation. Let $B = y(2015)$, and deduce $g(2015)$ using both equations.

Comment: @AkshatMishra In the now deleted question (reposted by OP) that Peterwhy linked to, OP says that "Yes, $y$ is another function".  $\quad$ (Though I'm inclined to agree with you that it's likely a typo).

Comment: @peterwhy Can you enter your answer in full detail in the answers section so I can rate it?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Can you explain your answer in more details in the answers section?

Comment: @AkshatMishra Assuming that $g$ function should be written instead of $y$ function in the second equation, how can this equation be solved?  Can you enter your answer in the question answer section?

Comment: @JafarManteghi Did the above comments help you to solve the problem and improve the post?

Comment: @peterwhy Honestly, I would say no.

Comment: @JafarManteghi Who said I had an answer?

Comment: @JafarManteghi - if the second equation involved the function $g$ instead of $y$, then the change of variables that Thomas Andrews has suggested transforms the left-hand side of the two equations to match, except $g$ is multiplied by $3$. This allows you to solve for $f(2x+1)$ and $g(x-1)$, from which the exact forms of both functions can be obtained, and the indicated value calculated. Unlike the unsolvable current situation, this would just be a simple algebra exercise that that I urge you to attempt yourself. If you don't know how, search for "solve a system of linear equations".

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $$g(t) = \begin{cases}1&t = 2015\\0&t \ne 2015\end{cases}$$
It follows that $$f(t) = \begin{cases}6049&t = 4033\\\frac{3t+1}2&t \ne 4033\end{cases}$$
and $$y(t) = \begin{cases}\frac{2020}3&t = 2015\\-\frac{2t}3&t \ne 2015\end{cases}$$
And $f(2015) + g(2015) = 3023 + 1 = 3024$.

Now suppose that $$g(t) = 3t + 5$$
Then $$f(t) = 0$$
and $$y(t) = \frac{t+5}3$$
Now $f(2015) + g(2015) = 0 + 6050 = 6050$.

There is nothing in the problem that eliminates either of these possibilities. The second equation puts no limits on the functions $f$ and $g$. It just defines a third function $y$ which is irrelevant to the question. In fact, by choosing an appropriate function $g$, you can obtain any value at all for $f(2015) + g(2015)$. The problem as stated has no solution.